# How to obtain ID of element that called onPlaceSelectedListener in Android

Tags: android, listener, google-places-api

I am totally new to android. I am implementing android Place Autocomplete api in my code. I have an activity containing 2 PlaceAutocompleteFragment and a onPlaceSelected Listener defined as follows :

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
    autocompleteFragment.setHint("Enter Source");
    autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_INDIA);

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment2 (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_fragment2);
    autocompleteFragment2.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
    autocompleteFragment2.setHint("Enter Destination");
    autocompleteFragment2.setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_INDIA);

    ........

    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    .....
    //need to know which PlaceAutocompleteFragment called this function, whether autocompleteFragement or autocompleteFragement2
    }
```

Whenever the method onPlaceSelected is called, I want to know which PlaceAutocompleteFragment called this function, whether autocompleteFragement or autocompleteFragement2

Rest of my code is working fine as of now.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue and here's my code:

```
    address2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete2);
    attributionsTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_attributions2);

    // Method that gets the address via Google Places and set it into the textView
    autocompleteFragment2 = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)

            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_fragment2);

    autocompleteFragment2.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());

            attributionsTextView2.setText(getString(R.string.place_autocomplete_search_hint, place
                    .getName(), place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber(), place
                    .getWebsiteUri(), place.getRating(), place.getId()));

            addr2 = place.getAddress().toString();
            Log.i("info", "addr2 : " + addr2);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(place.getAttributions())) {
                attributionsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAttributions().toString()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
        }
    });
    autocompleteFragment2.setHint("_ _ _ _ _ _");
```